# Clickhouse server startup is giving an error

Tags: clickhouse

getting an error on clickhouse startup however it is starting up fully and client has no issue in connecting and performing ops.

Any idea what below error means?

https://clickhouse.com/codebrowser/html_report/ClickHouse/src/Common/ErrorCodes.cpp.html

Thanks

```
chown --recursive clickhouse '/var/run/clickhouse-server/'
Will run su -s /bin/sh 'clickhouse' -c '/usr/bin/clickhouse-server --config-file /etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml --pid-file /var/run/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.pid --daemon'
Code: 302. DB::Exception: Child process was exited with return code 88. (CHILD_WAS_NOT_EXITED_NORMALLY) (version 21.9.4.35 (official build))
```

Comment: Return code 88 means clickhouse could not truncate a file - might be caused by files present in logdir or datadir belonging to another user.

Comment: hmm..thats interesting. during install using root all clickhouse folders ownership is transferred to clickhouse:clikhouse and when I use top, can see server running as clickhouse user.

Comment: Maybe you have ACL or other restriction for /var/lib/clickhouse or /var/log/clickhouse-server/ ?

Which OS you use for install? And how you install clickhouse ?

Comment: Its is installed on RHEL 7.9. I installed s/w using root and starting using another app Id which has sudo permission. Clickhouse is run as root using app id. Command used - "sudo clickhouse start". Error is due to usage of app id in spite of it having sudo permissions?